# Display xml feed - xml parser

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, feed

Is there anything in craft that can take an xml feed and display it on my site. 
It doesn't need to be saved as entries or anything. Simply just display the data. 
It's a sports xml feed and there will be fixtures/results and league tables.

I have seen this: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.feeds
But you only seem to be able to access a few fixed fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Feed Me](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe) plugin if you like! While it can save feed items as entries, you can use the [template tag](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe#template-example) which allows you to simply fetch feed data without actually saving it. Then you can loop through your feed items in your templates.

Let me know if you have any issues - I created the plugin, so happy to assist :)

Comment: Ah excellent - I had seen your plugin but never noticed the Template Option on it. Once I get access to the feed I will try it out and any issues get back to you.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little hidden away :)

Comment: Finally got around to implementing this - works 100% on my local environment but when I've uploaded to live server it's not working.
When I load the page nothing is returned and when I go to FeedMe section in the CMS it says: Unable to parse Feed URL.

Comment: Might be worth getting in touch with me via the Craft Slack channel, or submitting an issue through Github. Might be easier to debug there :)

Comment: a direct message on the slack channel or the help channel?